# Can't use single quots in qt creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When I use single quotes in number qt creator show warning for example in:

`for (unsigned int counter{1}; counter <= 10'000'000; ++counter)`

show below warning:

expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier

how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure at least C++14 support is enabled in the project file:

```
CONFIG += c++14
```